# My application can't comprehend SDL_KEYDOWN

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I scripted some basic navigation inside the app but then it didn't work so I reduced 
them to this

```
void CSystem::controls()
{
switch (mainEvent->type)
{
case SDL_KEYDOWN:
    switch (mainEvent->key.keysym.sym)
    {
    case SDLK_a:
        cout << "JKANAJIDJAIJIHVUIRBYVHRU" << endl;
        break;
    }
    break;

case SDL_KEYUP:
    switch (mainEvent->key.keysym.sym)
    {
    case SDLK_a:
        cout << "removed A" << endl;
        break;
    }
    break;
}
}
```

I saw the problem but I can't think of any other way to troubleshoot this, It read my KeyUp events but it won't read my KeyDown events, I tried to copy this code and paste it into  a game of mine, and it worked.

My brain's going haywire as to what's the problem, I checked the mainEvent and it was just the usual

```
SDL_Event* mainEvent = new SDL_CreateEvent();
```

I can't sense anything wrong with it this... is this a bug or something? I've been comtemplating of scratching the whole app just because of this minor setback.

Comment: Is there an error of some kind? I'm not sure what you're asking tbh.

Comment: Add a default to your switch statements: see what else the events bring and what other possible values you are getting for sym.

Comment: I already checked every function that was  before this, everything was fine, @Aesthete it won't read my KEYDOWN events, in other words, it can't sense if I'm pressing a button but it could sense if I lift my finger from a button. The code is functioning when I pasted it to my other app....

Answer (score 3):

You need to use SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent). Tell me if it worked :)

```
void CSystem::controls()
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent))
    {
    switch (mainEvent->type)
    {
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        switch (mainEvent->key.keysym.sym)
        {
        case SDLK_a:
            cout << "JKANAJIDJAIJIHVUIRBYVHRU" << endl;
            break;
        }
        break;

    case SDL_KEYUP:
        switch (mainEvent->key.keysym.sym)
        {
        case SDLK_a:
            cout << "removed A" << endl;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already did that in my game loop even before I posted this question, and it shouldn't be a poll event problem since it understood my key up event

Comment: The code you posted is right (i dont see anything wrong at least), if you say you pollEvent first. Maybe the problem is in the other part of the code... If you post i can take a look and see, cause i dont see any problem here.

Comment: I know, I already checked the entire code, I would really love to give you the whole code, but I divided them into classes so the game loop would just look like a mess of classes, is there  way to put .sln files here? aahahhaah seriously -_- ahhhhhh nevermind, I'll just throw this project into the recycle bin.....

Comment: :( best of luck to you sir.